# Winsock GET and POST Functions

Tags: c++, socket

This works fine so far, but I am looking for some advice as to how to better write this. My goal is to learn and incorporate current/latest C++ practices, and become a better programmer overall.

```
#include "HTTPRequest.h"


/*
    This function initalized Winsock
*/
bool HTTPRequest::InitWinsock()
{
    WSADATA WsaDat;

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &WsaDat) != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed To Start Winsocket With WSAStartup()\n";
        WSACleanup();
        return(false);
    }

    return(true);
}

std::string HTTPRequest::loopRecieve(SOCKET Sock)
{
    char recvBuf[256];  // Small 16bit Char For Transporting Data
    std::string outBuf; // Output String
    unsigned int nret = SOCKET_ERROR;

    while (nret != 0)
    {
        nret = recv(Sock, recvBuf, sizeof(recvBuf), 0);

        if ( (nret == SOCKET_ERROR) && (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK) )
        {
            std::cout << "Error Reading From Recv()\n";
        }
        else
        {
            outBuf.append(recvBuf, nret);
        }
    }

    return(outBuf);
}

void HTTPRequest::getWebPage(std::string Host, int Port, std::string Path)
{
    int nret;
    WSADATA WsaDat;
    SOCKET theSocket;

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &WsaDat) != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed To Initialize Winsock\n";
        return;
    }

    ADDRINFO hints;
    ADDRINFO* pResult               = nullptr;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_flags                  = AI_ALL;
    hints.ai_family                 = PF_INET;
    hints.ai_protocol               = IPPROTO_IPV4;

    nret = getaddrinfo((LPCSTR)Host.c_str(), nullptr, &hints, &pResult);
    if (nret != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed To Do GetAddrInfo()\n";
        return;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
    memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));
    servAddr.sin_family             = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr   = *((ULONG*)&(((sockaddr_in*)pResult->ai_addr)->sin_addr));
    servAddr.sin_port               = htons(Port);

    theSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (theSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout << "Socket Is Invalid, Is Winsock Initialized?\n";
        return;
    }

    nret = connect(theSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr));
    if (nret == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed To Connect To Host\n";
        return;
    }

    std::string request;
    request  = "GET " + Path + " HTTP/1.1"  + "\r\n";
    request += "Host: " + Host              + "\r\n";
    request += "Accept: */*\r\n";
    request += "Accept-Language: en-us\r\n";
    request += "Connection: close\r\n";
    request += "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0\r\n";
    request += "Referer: http://" + Host    + "\r\n";
    request += "\r\n";

    nret = send(theSocket, request.c_str(), request.length(), 0);
    if (nret == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed To Send To Host\n";
        return;
    }

    char recvBuf[16];   // Small 16bit Char For Transporting Data
    std::string outBuf; // Output String
    while (true)
    {
        nret = recv(theSocket, recvBuf, 16, 0);

        if (nret == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK) {
                std::cout << "Error Reading From Recv()\n";
                break;
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "Unknown Error Occured\n";
                break;
            }
        }
        if (nret == 0) {
            std::cout << "Recv() Socket Closed. So We're Done!\n";
            break;
        }
        else {
            outBuf.append(recvBuf, nret);
        }
    }

    // Display Data
    std::cout << "Data:\n" << outBuf << "\n";

    closesocket(theSocket);
    WSACleanup();
}

void HTTPRequest::postWebPage(std::string Host, int Port, std::string Path, std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> vPostReqs)
{
    int nret;
    WSADATA WsaDat;
    SOCKET theSocket;

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &WsaDat) != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed To Initialize Winsock\n";
        return;
    }

    ADDRINFO hints;
    ADDRINFO* pResult = nullptr;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_flags = AI_ALL;
    hints.ai_family = PF_INET;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_IPV4;

    nret = getaddrinfo((LPCSTR)Host.c_str(), nullptr, &hints, &pResult);
    if (nret != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed To Do GetAddrInfo()\n";
        return;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
    memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));
    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = *((ULONG*)&(((sockaddr_in*)pResult->ai_addr)->sin_addr));
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(Port);

    theSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (theSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout << "Socket Is Invalid, Is Winsock Initialized?\n";
        return;
    }

    nret = connect(theSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr));
    if (nret == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed To Connect To Host\n";
        return;
    }

    // Structure POST Data Properly
    std::string concatPostData;
    for (auto i : vPostReqs)
    {
        concatPostData += i.first + "=" + i.second + "&";
    }
    concatPostData.pop_back(); // Pop Off Extra &

    // Construct HEADER
    std::string header;
    header = "POST " + Path + " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    header += "Host: " + Host + ":" + std::to_string(Port) + "\r\n";
    header += "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0\r\n";
    header += "Referer: http://" + Host + "\r\n";
    header += "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    header += "Content-Length: " + std::to_string(concatPostData.length()) + "\r\n";
    header += "Accept-Charset: utf-8\r\n";
    header += "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
    header += concatPostData + "\r\n";
    header += "\r\n";

    nret = send(theSocket, header.c_str(), header.length(), 0);
    if (nret == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed To Send To Host\n";
        return;
    }

    std::string outBuf = loopRecieve(theSocket);

    // Display Data
    std::cout << "Data:\n" << outBuf << "\n";

    closesocket(theSocket);
    WSACleanup();
}


int main()
{
    HTTPRequest hReq;

    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> vPostReqs;

    vPostReqs.push_back(std::make_pair("ajax_login", "yes"));
    vPostReqs.push_back(std::make_pair("ACT", "10"));
    vPostReqs.push_back(std::make_pair("RET", "-2"));
    vPostReqs.push_back(std::make_pair("site_id", "1"));
    vPostReqs.push_back(std::make_pair("username", "Boobin"));
    vPostReqs.push_back(std::make_pair("password", "inboob"));
    vPostReqs.push_back(std::make_pair("auto_login", "1"));
    vPostReqs.push_back(std::make_pair("submit", "Submit"));

    hReq.postWebPage("postcatcher.in", 80, "/catchers/55f09e1c23e9dc0300001628", vPostReqs);

    system("pause");
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: ITs hard to review without the header file as there is lots of type information in there that would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use [`system()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4622772). It's generally considered bad practice and `pause` does not have a place in most programs. If you do intend on using `system()`, keep in mind that you have to explicitly flush `std::cout` before the call.

Even then, it's likely that you want an explicit flush for your error messages. Either use `std::cerr` or `std::cout.flush()` after each message.

**You have `InitWinsock()`, you never use it**

`WsaData` is a local variable in `InitWinsock()` making it completely useless.

You also never use `WsaData`. However after reading the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I'm not convinced you need to call `InitWinsock()` more than once. So just remove every instance of `WsaStartup()`. Here's example code from MSDN:

```
WORD wVersionRequested;
WSADATA wsaData;
int err;

wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD( 2, 2 );

err = WSAStartup( wVersionRequested, &wsaData );
if ( err != 0 ) {
    /* Tell the user that we could not find a usable */
    /* WinSock DLL.                                  */
    return;
}

/* Confirm that the WinSock DLL supports 2.2.*/
/* Note that if the DLL supports versions greater    */
/* than 2.2 in addition to 2.2, it will still return */
/* 2.2 in wVersion since that is the version we      */
/* requested.                                        */

if ( LOBYTE( wsaData.wVersion ) != 2 ||
        HIBYTE( wsaData.wVersion ) != 2 ) {
    /* Tell the user that we could not find a usable */
    /* WinSock DLL.                                  */
    WSACleanup( );
    return; 
}

/* The WinSock DLL is acceptable. Proceed. */
```

**Error messages**

The recommended way to get an error is to use [`WSAGetLastError()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737828%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), *not* `errno`:

> Error codes set by Windows Sockets are not made available through the
>   *errno* variable. Additionally, for the **getXbyY** class of functions,
>   error codes are not made available through the *h_errno* variable. The
>   **WSAGetLastError** function is intended to provide a reliable way for a
>   thread in a multithreaded process to obtain per-thread error
>   information.

Furthermore, the error constants prefixed by WSA are preferred:

```
// Example from MSDN
r = recv(...);
if (r == -1       /* (but see below) */
    && WSAGetLastError() == WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
    {...}
```

Furthermore, the error messages should be more descriptive. You may either choose to convert the error code to a string yourself or use [`FormatMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679351%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) as MSDN recommends.

**Minor issue**

`memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));` is not necessary in C++. You can zero initialize a struct with `servAddr = {0};`.

`struct some_struct` is redundant in C++. You can omit the `struct` keyword.

`(LPCSTR)some_string.c_str()` is redundant. [LPCSTR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc230350.aspx) is just a typedef to `const char*`.